# Rendering SVG images with compact framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, svg

I'm looking for a component to render SVG files in .Net Compact Framework (preferably 2.0) with the possibility to rotate and scale the image.

DXF would also be an alternative but SVG would be preferred.

Does anyone know of a component able to do this? Or have any recommendation on how to implement it?
At the moment I'm leaning toward just reading the SVG and rendering it with Piccolo2D but an easier solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any SVG components for .NETCF, but there is a [component](http://www.cadsofttools.com/en/products/cad_import_.net_for_compact_framework.html) for using DXF files in the Compact Framework.

Comment: Sadly this component is too slow for us and our past experience with the company isn't too great with too long response times to mail and so on.
+1 for the reply however! :)